# Apache Tomcat deploy war file with Spring Oauth2 authorization server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security, spring-oauth2

Implementation checking the war file if working.

The Spring Oauth2 Authorization Server is working fine when running in IDE, but when we try to check the war if it has same behavior, its having an error.
Have check that the controller endpoint is working but the build-in endpoint of Oauth2 is Not Found.

```
    <h1>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found</h1>
    <hr class="line" />
    <p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p>
    <p><b>Message</b> The requested resource [&#47;oauth2&#47;introspect] is not available</p>
    <p><b>Description</b> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
        willing to disclose that one exists.</p>
    <hr class="line" />
    <h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.75</h3>
```

Comment: Fix: i missed to extent SpringBootServletInitializer in main class